# get values from dropdown list in php in a loop?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post, foreach

I want to get values from dropdown list and values indexes too. A loop runs each time with different length e.g one time loop runs 5 times and creates 5 rows. next time may be 30 times and creates 30 rows. Each row has 2 dropdown list. Please help me how i can get value of each dropdown list and indexes too. 
Here is code:

```
    '
    <div>
                <form name="viewdata" method="post" onChange="this.form.submit()">
                    <table>
                        <tr colspan=2>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="BSSE" value="BSSE" >BSSE&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</input></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="BCS" value="BCS" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBCS&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</input></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="BSTN" value="BSTN" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspBSTN&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>                       
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="MTH" value="MTH" >MTH&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</input></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="MGT" value="MGT" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspMGT&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</input></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="EEE" value="EEE" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspEEE&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</input></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="CSC" value="CSC" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspCSC&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</input></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="HUM" value="HUM" >&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbspHUM&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</input></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">View</button>
            </td>
                </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </div>
            <form method = "post">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">

<?php
$programs_title = array();
$programs_id = array();


$courses_title = array();
$courses_id = array();

$classes = array();
$time_table = array();

$sections_id = array();
$faculty_selected_course = array();

$allocation1 = array();
$allocation2 = array();
$course_loop_array = array();

if(isset($_POST['BSSE'])) {$programs_title[]=$_POST['BSSE'];}
if(isset($_POST['BCS'])) {$programs_title[]=$_POST['BCS'];}
if(isset($_POST['BSTN'])) {$programs_title[]=$_POST['BSTN'];}

if(isset($_POST['MTH'])) {$courses_id[]=$_POST['MTH'];}
if(isset($_POST['MGT'])) {$courses_id[]=$_POST['MGT'];}
if(isset($_POST['EEE'])) {$courses_id[]=$_POST['EEE'];}
if(isset($_POST['CSC'])) {$courses_id[]=$_POST['CSC'];}
if(isset($_POST['HUM'])) {$courses_id[]=$_POST['HUM'];}

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db('dims') or die("cannot connect to database");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE email_id='hhh@comsats.edu.pk'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $other_faculty[] = $row1['first_name'];
}

foreach ($programs_title as $prog) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM program WHERE program_title = '$prog'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql);

if(is_null($result1)){
    echo die(mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $programs_id[] = $row['program_id'];
}

}

foreach ($programs_id as $prog_id) {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM time_table WHERE program_id = '$prog_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(is_null($result)){
    echo die(mysql_error());
}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if(is_array($sections_id)){
       if(!in_array($prog_id."-".$row['section_id'],$sections_id)){
        $sections_id[] = $prog_id."-".$row['section_id'];
    } 
    }
    else{
        $sections_id[] = $prog_id."-".$row['section_id'];
    }


}

}

$section_loop = 1;

foreach ($sections_id as $class) {

    $courses = array();

    $split = preg_split('/-/', $class);

    $program = $split[0];
    $section = $split[1];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM time_table WHERE program_id = '$program' AND section_id = '$section'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(is_null($result)){
    echo die(mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if(is_array($courses)){
            if(!in_array($row['course_code'], $courses)){
            $courses[] = $row['course_code'];
            }
        }
        else{
            $courses[] = $row['course_code'];
        }

    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM program WHERE program_id = '$program'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(is_null($result)){
    echo die(mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $program = $row['program_title'];
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM section WHERE section_id = '$section'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if(is_null($result)){
    echo die(mysql_error());
    }

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $section = $row['section_title'];
    }

    if(!in_array($program."-".$section, $classes)){
        $classes[] = $program."-".$section;
    }

    /*foreach ($courses_id as $course) {
        if(!in_array($program."-".$section."-".$course, $time_table)){
        $time_table[] = $program."-".$section."-".$course;
    }
    }*/
    ?>

    <thead>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <th colspan=6><?php echo $program."-".$section."<br>"; ?></th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Course Code</th>
            <th>Course Title</th>
            <th>Class/Lab</th>
            <th>Faculty</th>
            <th>Other Faculty</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<?php
    $course_loop =1;

    foreach ($courses as $course) {
        unset($faculty_selected_course);
            if($course!='JUMMA'){
                foreach ($courses_id as $value) {
                    if(stristr($course, $value)){ ?>
    <tbody>
<?php

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM course WHERE course_code='$course'";
                        $result2 = mysql_query($sql);

                        if(is_null($result2)){
                            echo die(mysql_error());
                        }

                        while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
                            $course_title = $row2['course_title'];
                            $course_credit_hour = $row2['course_credit_hour'];
                        }

                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM faculty_course_choice WHERE course_choice1='$course' OR course_choice2='$course' OR course_choice3='$course'";
                        $result3 = mysql_query($sql);

                        if(is_null($result3)){
                            echo die(mysql_error());
                        }

                        while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)){
                            if($course == $row3['course_choice1']){
                                $course_priority = 1;
                                $user = $row3['user_id'];
                            }

                            elseif($course == $row3['course_choice2']){
                                $course_priority = 2;
                                $user = $row3['user_id']."<br>";
                            }

                            elseif($course == $row3['course_choice3']){
                                $course_priority = 3;
                                $user = $row3['user_id']."<br>";
                            }

                            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE user_id='$user'";
                            $result4 = mysql_query($sql);

                            while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4)){
                                $faculty_selected_course[] = $course_priority."::".$row4['first_name'];
                            }
                        }
                        again:
                        ?>
                        <tr class="odd gradeX">
                        <th><?php echo $course_loop++; ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $course; ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $course_title; ?></th>
                        <th><?php 
                        if($course_credit_hour==3){
                            echo "Class";
                            $allocation1 [] = $program."-".$section."-".$course."-Class";
                            $allocation2 [] = $program."-".$section."-".$course."-Class";
                        }
                        elseif($course_credit_hour==4){
                            echo "Lab";
                            $allocation1 [] = $program."-".$section."-".$course."-Lab";
                            $allocation2 [] = $program."-".$section."-".$course."-Lab";
                            $course_credit_hour--; ?>
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            <select name= "allocation1[]" class="form-control ">
                                <option>Select Faculty</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($faculty_selected_course as $faculty) { ?>
                                <option><?php echo $faculty;  ?></option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select> 
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            <select name= "allocation2[]" class="form-control ">
                                <option>Select Other Faculty</option>
                                <?php
                                foreach ($other_faculty as $otherfaculty) { ?>
                                <option><?php echo $otherfaculty;  ?></option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </th>

                        </tr>
                        <?php goto again;
                        }
                        ?>
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            <select name= "allocation1[]" class="form-control ">
                            <option>Select Faculty</option>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($faculty_selected_course as $faculty) { ?>
                            <option><?php echo $faculty;  ?></option>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                        </th>

                        <th>
                            <select name= "allocation2[]" class="form-control ">
                                <option>Select Other Faculty</option>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($other_faculty as $otherfaculty) { ?>
                            <option><?php echo $otherfaculty;  ?></option>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                            </select>
                        </th>

                        </tr>

                        <?php
                    }

                }
            }
    }
    $get_index = $program."-".$section."-".$course_loop;
    $course_loop_array [] = $get_index;
}  
?>

                        <tr>
                            <th colspan="7" >
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Allocate</button>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>   

                                </table>
                            </form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['allocation1'])){
$output = count($_POST['allocation1']);
echo $output;
foreach ($_POST['allocation1'] as $value) {
    if($value == 'Select Other Faculty' OR $value == 'Select Faculty'){

    }
    else{
        echo $value."<br>";
    }

}
}
$allocation1 = $_POST['allocation1'];
foreach ($allocation1 as $value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
}

foreach ($course_loop_array as $lue) {
    echo $lue."<br>";
}

?>


                </div>'
```

//loop ends

'

Comment: A lot of things in this are confusing me. First of all, the <th> should be used only for the header of the table, not for data elements that go below the header. Why are both the select names the same thing, why are they array names (with [] in the name makes the POST data of an array type when received by PHP) - does that mean there are multiple rows of select elements? Why are the select names in the style of PHP variables with a $ in front? Why are there no values included in the <option> elements?

Comment: So what do you want - you want the name of each select as what?

Comment: two select names is not same thing. one select contains few faculty members name while other contains all faculty member contains. One can select from few faculty members and can also select from all faculty members list but not both at same time. and there are multiple rows. each row has 2 select options (1 is few faculty member, 2 is all faculty members). what will i get if i include value in <option> ?

Comment: If you include value as shown by @Marco's answer below, the browser will send that as the value of the $_POST variable with the select "name" for the chosen options. Now I am beginning to understand your request. So they need to be able to chose from one or the other select boxes, but not both at once, I see.

Comment: Writing what I think is the answer to your problem is right now, will post it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking for, but the code should look something like this to make sense:

```
<th>
    <select name="first_allocation[<?=$rowId?>]">
        <option>Select Faculty</option>
        <? foreach ($faculties as $faculty) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$faculty?>"><?=$faculty?></option>
        <? } ?>
    </select> 
</th>
<th>
    <select name="second_allocation[<?=$rowId?>]">
        <option>Select Other Faculty</option>
        <? foreach ($faculties as $faculty) { ?>
            <option value="<?=$faculty?>"><?=$faculty?></option>
        <? } ?>
    </select>
</th>
```

That way you would receive something like this when the user submits the form:

```
$_POST = array(
    'first_allocation' = array(
        232 => 'BCS-IIIB-CSC509-Class',
        372 => 'BCS-IIIB-CSC509-Class',
        // ...
    ),
    'second_allocation' = array(
        232 => 'BCS-IIIB-CSC509-Class',
        372 => 'BCS-IIIB-CSC509-Class',
        // ...
    ),
);
```

Where 232 and 373 are the respective values of $rowId, changing on each iteration of the outside loop.

If you already have the selected faculties and want to mark them as such use this:

```
<option value="<?=$faculty?>"<?=($first_allocation[$rowId] === $faculty ? ' selected' : '')?>>
    <?=$faculty?>
</option>
```

Comment: this will work in loop? how i can know that "first_allocation" belongs to which row?

Comment: See my edit, just understood your question correctly. Or did I?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the dollar sign from the `name` attribute values, and use a different name for the two columns:

```
<select name="allocation1[]" ...


<select name="allocation2[]" ...
```

Then when the user submits the form you can access:

```
$allocations1 = $_POST['allocation1'];
$allocations2 = $_POST['allocation2'];
```

The indexes of these arrays represent the row number minus 1 (since it starts with zero).

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are after

The main file, maybe "mainListOfStuff.php" you can have something like this

```
<form action="processForm.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Main faculty members</th>
            <th>Other factulty members</th>
        </tr>
        <!-- Start of your loop for table rows -->
        <?php
            // YOUR LOOP FOR THE ROWS OF THE TABLE
            // My example loop for this explanation: for (var $i = 0; $i < count([SOME LENGTH OF ROWS]); $i++) {
            // My example start of row: echo "<tr>";
        ?>
                <td>
                    <select name="allocationMain[]" class="form-control mainFaculty">
                        <option selected value="0">Not from this faculty</option>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($faculty_selected_course as $faculty) {
                                echo "<option value=\"". $faculty ."\">". $faculty ."</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select> 
                </td><td>
                    <select name="allocationOther[]" class="form-control otherFaculty">
                        <option selected value="0">Not from this faculty</option>
                        <?php
                            foreach ($other_faculty as $otherfaculty) {
                                echo "<option value=\"". $otherfaculty ."\">". $otherfaculty ."</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
        <!-- End of your loop for table rows -->
        <?php
            // My example end of row: echo "<tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

You can clean up the above page "mainListOfStuff.php" by putting in some jQuery that swaps the selected answer to "Not from this faculty" when someone swaps the select boxes

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("select.otherFaculty").on("change keyup", function(){ // If they choose something in a row in the other faculty
                                                                // Then change the main select to the first "0" value option
            $(this).closest("tr").find("select.mainFaculty").val(0);
        });
        $("select.mainFaculty").on("change keyup", function(){
            $(this).closest("tr").find("select.otherFaculty").val(0);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Example of above code here > https://jsfiddle.net/9n4ypboj/

Then in processForm.php you do this:

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_POST["allocationMain"])) exit();   // If no data was submitted then stop the php script here.


    $mainAllocations = $_POST["allocationMain"];    // Both of these arrays should be the same length
    $otherAllocations = $_POST["allocationOther"];  // if the form was submitted properly

    $chosenAllocations = [];

    for( $i = 0; $i < count($mainAllocations); $i++ ) {
        if ( $mainAllocations[$i] == 0 ) {  // If they have not selected "Not from this faculty" for the main select column,
                                            // then select the value in the other select column
            $chosenAllocations[$i] = $otherAllocations[$i];
        } else {
            $chosenAllocations[$i] = $mainAllocations[$i];
        }
    }

    // Use the $chosenAllocations for the rest of your PHP processing

?>
```